# Delimiter takes all the columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a prn file where I have 6 columns and I need to take the first column and compare that the string entered is the same as the names that are in the register.
The problem is that it takes too the second column because contains this string

This is the code

```
name = input('Enter a name to find: ')
with open(fileName) as File:  
    reader = csv.reader(File,delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        if name in row[0]:
            print(row)
```

This is the result I got, I just need the first register

[image]

This is the file where I'm getting the information
[image]

Comment: can you pls post first  2 or 3 sample lines of the file you are reading the data from?

Comment: @instinct246 I just put it, thanks

Comment: I edited my answer below. pls use   if name == row[0] rather than         if name in row[0] - you will get only name1. Pls accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Didn't see the message, I solved anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code is fine. It is just that the delimiter in the original file. You need to check that and pass that as delimiter argument to csv.reader instead of a "\t". It may not be tab delimited in your original input file. It could be a whitespace or multiple whitespaces.
As I do not have access to your input file, here I tried to simulate your problem with some sample data.

**Sample data:** (Created a white space delimited file named sample.csv). The content looks as below:

```
name1 surname1 is 345
name2 surname1 is 678
name3 surname1 is 90
name13 surname12 is xyz
```

Read the file with the conditions you mentioned.

**1: Read with delimiter as tab. Got unexpected results as you are getting.**

```
import csv
nm = input ('Enter a name: ')
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as fh:
    for line in (csv.reader(fh, delimiter = "\t")):
        if nm in line[0]:
            print (line)
```

o/p:

```
Enter a name: name1
['name1 surname1 is 345']
['name2 surname1 is 678']
['name3 surname1 is 90']
['name13 surname12 is xyz']
```

**2: Read with delimiter as one whitespace and used "==" instead of "in" for the if comparison. Got the correct result:**

```
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as fh:
    for line in (csv.reader(fh, delimiter = " ")):
        if nm == line[0]:
            print (line)
```

o/p

```
['name1', 'surname1', 'is', '345']
```